# C++ int* wrapper yields large number rather than the int assigned

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a wrapper for int* in C++. Currently, it's not going very well.

For the sake of testing, I've included two very taboo lines at the start, please ignore them.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Number {
public:
    int32_t* value_32;

    Number(int32_t value) {
        value_32 = &value;
    }
};

int main() {
    int32_t v = 13;
    Number* n = new Number(v);
    cout << *(n->value_32) << "\n";
}
```

I would expect this code yields an output of `13`, but it gives a random large number, ex: `1833022464`. Why is this the case?

*Note: changing int32_t to int yields the same problem*

Comment: The problem is with `value_32 = &value`. You make `value_32` point to the *local* variable `value`. And the life-time of `value` will end when the constructor function ends, leaving you with an invalid pointer. Why are you working with pointers to begin with?

Comment: And talking about pointers that aren't needed, why are you doing `new Number(v)`? Do you come from Java or C# or similar language where one needs to use `new` to create objects? It's not needed in C++. You can just do `Number n(v);` and have an object named `n`.

Comment: Side notes: (1) [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) (2) [What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Crashes on my machine.  *Why is this the case?*  **Undefined behavior**.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. I realized why I was getting this shortly after posting the question. To address your comments, @Someprogrammerdude I can just do Number n(v), although I don't see how that is relevant to the question. To wohlstad, I specifically mentioned that I know it is bad practice, it was just to make testing easier.

Comment: Another side not, don't use new if you don't really have to, naked new/deletes should be taboo too ;) . When you have no polymorphism new (or even better std::make_unique) is usually not needed at all

Comment: *I can just do Number n(v), although I don't see how that is relevant to the question* -- It is relevant in terms of guaging whether you are learning C++ properly. -- *I specifically mentioned that I know it is bad practice, it was just to make testing easier* -- It would have been easier just to type in `#include <iostream>` instead of the non-standard `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`.  Having `using namespace std;`, even though it isn't recommended, is still standard.  Having that "bits" header -- no excuse to have that at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're taking the address of a temporary. The lifetime of `value` ends, and `value_32` is left pointing to invalid memory. Dereferencing it invokes [*undefined* behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior). Seeing a different number than you expect is one outcome. The number you expected is another valid outcome. Or your program crashing.

Now, you could pass a reference to an int, but even there you have to worry about lifetime issues.

```
class Number {
public:
    int32_t* value_32;

    Number(int32_t &value) : value_32(&value) { }
};
```

Raw pointers in modern C++ are rarely necessary, so you'd really want to ask yourself *why* you're writing code like this, and whether there's a better way to accomplish your goal.

I would also suggest you read:

- [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)
- [What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/whats-the-problem-with-using-namespace-std)